# Kio estas la diferenco inter "skatolo" kaj "kesto"?

Tags: word-difference

Cxu *skatolo* kaj *kesto* estas sinonimoj, aux cxu estas diferenco inter ili? Kiam mi uzu *skatolo* kaj kiam mi uzu *kesto*?

Answer (score 5):

**Short and sweet: a *kesto* is bigger.**

- *Skatolo* is a box or a can.
- *Kesto* is more like a chest or a crate.

---

Mallonga respondo: "kesto" estas pli granda.

Comment: Vidu la ekzemplojn en PIV - plejparte kesto estas pli granda, sed ne cxiam. Ekzemple, cigarkesto ne estas grandega kesto.

Answer (score 2):

Permesu al mi citi pravigojn el [la Lernu-forumo](http://lernu.net/eo/forumo/temo/19083):

> *Kesto* estas pli fortika ol *skatolo*, kaj ĉiam granda.
>
> En sia traduko de *La Batalo de l' Vivo*, Zamenhof metis *fajreltenaj
>   kestoj kun pendantaj seruroj* por *boxes, padlocked and fireproof.* En
>   *Fabeloj de Andersen*, li asertis ke kesto *staris en angulo*, aŭ ke ĝi
>   enhavas monon aŭ oron.
>
> Kontraŭ tio, en *Marta* li skribis *ŝi malfermis longforman skatolon, en
>   kiu troviĝis ilaro por desegnado.*
>
> En la *Universala Vortaro* oni trovas:
>
> > **kest'** caisse, coffre | chest, box | Kiste, Kasten, Lade | ящикъ | skrzynia.
> >
> > **——tir'kest'** tiroir | drawer | Schublade | выдвижной ящикъ | szuflada.
> >
> > **skatol'** boîte | small box, case | Büchse, Schachtel | коробка |
> >     pudełko.

Comment: Obviously not necessarily valid for Esperanto, but in German a _Schachtel_ (which to me seems to be the origin of _skatolo_) is either made of cardboard or light wood. It is more transient than a _Kiste_, which is made of more solid material, and usually bigger.

Answer (score 2):

Kesto estas kaj fortika kaj granda. Se la ujo estas aŭ ne-fortika (ekzemple farita el kartono) aŭ malgranda, oni kutime preferas la vorton "skatolo". Sed la limo inter la du ne ĉiam estas klara.

Answer (score 1):

En la angla:

- Skatolo = Box
- Kesto = Chest or case

Skatolo:
[image]

Kesto:

[image]

Poŝtkesto:

[image]

> Ujeto diversforma, fermebla kaj malfermebla, el solida substanco kiaj
>   ligno, kartono, plasto, metalo...http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/skatol.html#skatol.0o
>
> Ujo ligna, metala, plasta aŭ el alia materialo, ofte en formo de orta
>   paralelepipedo. http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/kest.html#kest.0o

Comment: La vikipedio montras skatolan bildon kiel 'kesto'.
https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kesto

Strange!

Comment: @IvanGarcia Cxu vi pensas tion? Laux mi aspektas gxuste kiel perkomputile desegnita *chest*. Ial la priskribo diras "kesto el kartono", tio ja strangas kaj konfuzigas!

Comment: Iu ĵus ŝanĝis ĝin en Vikipedio. Dankon.